# Count occurences of lists efficiently

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, count

I have a list containing a few millions of lists, these sublists have a few distinct possible values, maybe 10 to 100.

I want to count the number of occurrences of these values.

The code below works but it is very slow. Can we do this faster ?

```r
count_by_list <- function(lst, var_nm = as.character(substitute(lst)), count_nm = "n"){
  unique_lst <- unique(lst)
  res <- tibble::tibble(!!var_nm := unique_lst, !!count_nm := NA)
  for(i in seq_along(unique_lst)){
    res[[count_nm]][[i]] <- sum(lst %in% res[[var_nm]][i])
  }
  res
}

x <- list(
  list(a=1, b=2),
  list(a=1, b=2),
  list(b=3),
  list(b=3, c=4))

count_by_list(x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x                    n
#>   <list>           <int>
#> 1 <named list [2]>     2
#> 2 <named list [1]>     1
#> 3 <named list [2]>     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I tried hashing with the library `digest` but it was actually slower, and getting worse as n increases :

```
library(digest)
count_by_list2 <- function(lst, var_nm = as.character(substitute(lst)), count_nm = "n"){
  unique_lst <- unique(lst)
  digested   <- vapply(lst, digest, character(1))
  res        <- as.data.frame(table(digested))
  names(res) <- c(var_nm, count_nm)
  res[[1]] <- unique_lst
  res
}
```

If you need to benchmark you can use `x_big <- unlist(replicate(10000 ,x, F),  recursive = FALSE)`.

I added the tags `rcpp` and `parallel processing` as these might help, these are not constraints on the answers.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but are you trying to count the number of unique lists in your "master" list?

Comment: no, for each unique list I want to know its number of occurrences. In my example I have 3 unique lists, the first is present 2 times, others only once. There are the numbers I'm after.

Comment: Technically not an appropriate question as you are not supposed to ask "please rewrite this in (preferably parallelised) C++ for me".

Comment: This is not what I was trying to ask, I don't even know if C++ is the way to go Dirk, is it ? if it is I'll be happy to get some hints and I might come back and edit, or ask a more specific question

Comment: But it is what you asked ;-)  -- so maybe time to remove the two tags?  I would think that `data.table` will already give you _very_ fast ordering and counting (remember: base R tooks its algorithm) and possible parallelism via openmp.

Comment: I don't think we agree on what tagging implies, I'm looking up the FAQ and meta and will remove if it changes my mind. To me part of the question is that rcpp and parallel processing might be relevant, so tags are appropriate, I'll also listen if you want to argue further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach is 30 times faster than OP original loop for the `x_big` example. One notable precaution is that if any element of a sublist contains more than one record, this approach would fail.

```
library(data.table)

molten_lst <- rbindlist(x, fill = T)
cnt_lst <- molten_lst[, .N, names(molten_lst)]

tibble(x = cnt_lst[, 
                   list(apply(.SD, 1, function(x) as.list(na.omit(x)))),
                   .SDcols = names(molten_lst),
                   by = .(seq_len(nrow(cnt_lst)))]$V1,
           n = cnt_lst[['N']])
```

Here are two backup approaches. I ran into NSE / quasi-quotation issues, so the `!!var_nam` was simplified. The first approach is some tweaks to your original function - primarily by filtering the `lst` during the loop.

```
enhanced_loop <- function(lst, var_nm = as.character(substitute(lst)), count_nm = "n"){
  unique_lst <- unique(lst)
  cnts <- vector('integer', length(unique_lst))

  for (i in seq_along(unique_lst)[-length(unique_lst)]){
    ind <- lst %in% unique_lst[i]
    lst <- lst[!ind]
    cnts[i] <- sum(ind)
  }
  cnts[length(unique_lst)] <- length(lst)
  tibble::tibble(x := unique_lst, !!count_nm := cnts)
}
```

And this takes the loop to the logical conclusion - using `match()` instead of `%in%` so effort is not duplicated:

```
tabulate_match <- function(lst, var_nm = as.character(substitute(lst)), count_nm = "n"){
  unique_lst <- unique(lst)
  cnts <- tabulate(match(lst, unique_lst))
  tibble::tibble(x := unique_lst, !!count_nm := cnts)
}
```

**Performance:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 13
  expression                min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr
  <bch:expr>              <bch> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int>
1 molten_dt                25ms  25.1ms     39.7     2.71MB     0        5
2 tabulate_match(x_big)   237ms 247.2ms      3.41    1.42MB     2.05     5
3 enhanced_loop(x_big)    344ms 352.6ms      2.82    2.83MB     1.69     5
4 table_sapply            381ms 384.9ms      2.59    3.76MB     7.77     5
5 vapply_tab_match(x_big) 412ms 429.3ms      2.14    4.21MB     3.85     5
6 dt_thing(x_big)         442ms 464.6ms      2.15    2.83MB     7.31     5
7 count_by_list(x_big)    759ms 768.4ms      1.24     3.4MB     2.23     5
```

Comment: It's nice, I'll benchmark it with the others, it's not general though, in some of my real cases I will have some nested lists, this assumes that I can flatten everything as a first step

Comment: oh and it also assumes my list is sorted, the example is but it's really not the general case.

Comment: `tabulate_match()` was exactly what I was trying to do in my original solution. +1

Comment: I'm choosing this one as I can make it work for my case and that the performance improvement is substantial, but users please mind the precaution mentioned at the top, @sindr_baldur's solution seems general however.

Answer (score 5):

Here is something quick and dirty that shaves off the original solution.

```
cbl2 <- function(x) {
  xcv <- vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) paste(x[i]), character(1))
  xcv_count <- table(match(xcv, xcv))
  tibble(x = x[as.integer(names(xcv_count))], n = as.vector(xcv_count))  
}
```

Some playing around with `data.table` again shortened the run time:

```
cbl3 <- function(x) {
  data.table(xlist = x)[, xstring := paste(xlist), by = 1:length(x)
                        ][, .(x = xlist[1], .N), by = xstring
                          ][, .(x, n = N)
                            ][, as_tibble(.SD)]
}
```

Comment: I save half of the time with this indeed. I tried to break it a bit but it resisted so far :)

Comment: (+ @Moody_Mudskipper, too:) avoiding the overhead of `paste` by using only `as.character` (as the function in `vapply`) seems a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code can work

```
df <- data.frame(table(sapply(x_big, function(v) paste0(c(names(z<-unlist(v)),z),collapse = ","))))
```

which gives

```
> df
     Var1 Freq
1 a,b,1,2    2
2     b,3    1
3 b,c,3,4    1
```

- **runtime comparison**: 4e5 elements in `x_big`

```
x_big <- unlist(replicate(100000 ,x, F),  recursive = FALSE)

# my solution
t1 <- Sys.time()
df <- data.frame(table(sapply(x_big, function(v) paste0(c(names(z<-unlist(v)),z),collapse = ","))))
w1 <- Sys.time() - t1

#author's solution
t2 <- Sys.time()
count_by_list <- function(lst, var_nm = as.character(substitute(lst)), count_nm = "n"){
  unique_lst <- unique(lst)
  res <- tibble::tibble(!!var_nm := unique_lst, !!count_nm := NA)
  for(i in seq_along(unique_lst)){
    res[[count_nm]][[i]] <- sum(lst %in% res[[var_nm]][i])
  }
  res
}
count_by_list(x_big)
w2 <- Sys.time()-t2

> c(w1,w2)
Time differences in secs
[1] 3.591747 8.058480
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if you had a list like the following: `list(b=1, c=2)`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur well...you are right...that's an issue in my solution. Thanks a lot, I will try to fix it